# Is there any way to find the width of a character in a fixed-width font, given the size, style, etc.?

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, textbox

Is there any way to find the width of a character (the distance between the beginning of a character to the beginning of the next character) in a given fixed width font in a given size, style, etc. (e.g. Courier New, Bold, size 16)?

Basically I need to determine what the width of a TextBox should be for *n* characters per line (the Font is only known at runtime so I cannot simply hardcode the numbers).

What is the best way to find the width of a character? Or is there a better way to determine the width of the TextBox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I once wrote an extension method for strings to get its screen size depending on the font family, size etc.

```
public static Size GetScreenSize(this string text, FontFamily fontFamily, double fontSize, FontStyle fontStyle, FontWeight fontWeight, FontStretch fontStretch)
{
    fontFamily = fontFamily ?? new TextBlock().FontFamily;
    fontSize = fontSize > 0 ? fontSize : new TextBlock().FontSize;
    var typeface = new Typeface(fontFamily, fontStyle, fontWeight, fontStretch);
    var ft = new FormattedText(text ?? string.Empty, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, typeface, fontSize, Brushes.Black);
    return new Size(ft.Width, ft.Height);
}
```

You can use it this way:

```
"Hello World".GetScreenSize(fontFamily, 12, FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Normal, FontStretches.Normal);
```

You can also use the default style of `TextBlock`:

```
"Hello World".GetScreenSize(null, 0, FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Normal, FontStretches.Normal);
```

You can also have a look at [extensionmethod.net](http://www.extensionmethod.net/Details.aspx?ID=484) for the same information.

**Edit:**

If you have a fixed-width font, you could calculate the width using an arbitrary character like this:

```
double width = "X".GetScreenSize(fontFamily, 12, FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Normal, FontStretches.Normal) * numbersOfCharacters;
```

Comment: There isn't any way to get the character size from the FontFamily itself? This information has to be stored somewhere...

Comment: Yeah but can't you find the width of one particular character?

Comment: If you're using a fixed-width font, you could calculate the width of a arbitrary character using the way above and multiply it by the number of characters you use. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Yeah but I was asking if you could extract the information directly from the font, style, etc. without rendering it.

Comment: If there is a possibility, I don't know it ;) Using FormattedText will actually not render it in your UI, just in memory.

Comment: I know it only renders in memory but it just seems like you are doing extra work.